# WP7 Dotfuscator error on Windows Server 2008, thinks assembly does not target WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, dotfuscator

I've successfully run dotfuscator locally with my WP7 app. However, when I try to run it on our build server, which is a Windows Server 2008 SP2, I get the following error:

```
LICENSED TO: xxxxxx xxxxxx
SERIAL #: [serial number here]
Adding assembly "AssemblyName.dll" as input has been disallowed. Only assemblies targeting the Windows Phone platform are supported in this edition of Dotfuscator.
```

I'm not sure what's going on. The only thing I can think of, is that dotfuscator for Windows Phone isn't supported on Windows Server 2008, but I didn't find anything to confirm or deny that. The Dotfuscator on the server is the same version as the one on my local machine. Has anyone run into this before? Any solutions or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the issue was not with Windows Server 2008, but with a path in the dotfuscator configuration xml file. The problem was that dotfuscator was showing an incorrect error message, leading me to believe there was a problem with the file itself, not that the path was wrong. Dotfuscator should have a better error message for this case. Even a simple "file not found" error would be better than the current error.

Answer (score 0):

Dotfuscator should run fine on Windows 2008, the issue may be that the assembly type detection code has an issue.

If your assemblies are targeting WP7 then you should not be receiving this message.  Can you send your XAP to support@preemptive.com (or include it in a support ticket at http://www.preemptive.com/contact/supportrequestform)